# Add Skype contact in Gmail signature

Tags: gmail, email-signature

I am using Gmail and want to add my Skype contact in signature. I know there are ways to add a Skype button using 3rd party plugins and extensions but is there a way where I can add my Skype ID to text and when the user clicks on my ID, he / she is asked to add it to his / her Skype contacts?

I tried using `skype:my_skype_username?add` in the "Web address" field

[image: screen shot]

but it doesn't work. I don't know much about HTML. Has someone already done it without using 3rd party plugins, just by using what Gmail provides? If so, it'd be great you could share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to add a Skype account as a Gmail signature then you have to create a redirecting method like mentioned in the link below. Here's sample HTML:

```
<html><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=skype:USERNAME?chat" />Redirecting to Skype... you can close this tab/window.</html>
```

Source : *[add-skype-click-to-call-button-in-gmail-signature](http://web.archive.org/web/20150204095007/http://anees.co/add-skype-click-to-call-button-in-gmail-signature/)*

Comment: I tried this solution and it works but I want the tab to close automatically after I have accepted the request from Chrome asking to launch the application. I have no knowledge in HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

For the legacy, [Skype button is no longer supported](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA605/is-the-legacy-skype-button-still-supported) and it was removed in May 2015 by Microsoft, however adding a Skype account in one click still works.

So please use the following URL as the workaround:

```
http://hatscripts.com/addskype?USERNAME_HERE
```

since `skype:USERNAME?call` [Skype URI syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn745878.aspx) doesn't work for Gmail signature.

Or read the instructions from [this page](https://hatscripts.com/addskype/).

---

Related:

- [Create application link to Skype profile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16177332/55075) at Stack Overflow
- [Using HTML to do a Skype call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3855650/55075) at Stack Overflow
- [CallTo URL Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709071(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In Gmail signature we got two options:

1. website
2. email

So we stick to first option and the best way is shorten the link and change it to http one:

Example : skype:-username?chat    or skype:-username?add 
use one online shrorten link website like https://is.gd/index.php
this website will change the code to URL like: https://is.gd/RQVmSb
and you may put this link to your signature